# How to show code errors while running

Tags: php, apache, error-handling

previously i had php5.1 installed and i recently upgraded to php5.3.

In previous versions all syntax errors and other errors were display in page whenever error occurs and it was easy for me to debug.

But now whenever there is error in page it just stops processing and shows blank.

i tried adding following too:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

at top of page but didn't work. Any suggestions?

Edit more info:

when i do phpinfo(), it shows my configuration file: c:\php\php.ini.
Further on opening and editing php.ini file i found:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

Edit More Info:
Corrected error_reporting to E_ALL | E_STRICT.
Found it almost blanks out whenever the error is being generated from code inside function or class.

Comment: Did you restart httpd after making changes to php.ini?

Comment: yeah surely... i even restarted my pc too...

Comment: Do a search for php.ini file(s), chances are you have more than one.

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

Comment: Do you have any type of caching to turned on?

Answer (score 0):

> whenever there is error in page

What level of error? Is it fatal or not?
If fatal - then your in-code settings (`error_reporting()` and `ini_set`) are not used at all: php.ini ones are used instead.

IMO, you've provided insufficient info: at least `php.ini` values you have for `error_reporting` and `error_log` directives needed.

Comment: As I've undrestood, you have control over "errors", am I right? If so - then what kind of errors are you trying to catch: fatal or not fatal ones?

Comment: Hm. Wait. `E_ALL & E_STRICT` (with binary _and_) means that you're interested in `E_NONE` errors :) If you want to catch `E_ALL` **and** `E_STRICT` - then binary _or_ should be used: `E_ALL | E_STRICT`. Try this.